# Visual C++ Data in MFC Dialog Box not Displaying

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, dialog, resources

I am new to C++ and I am playing around with GUI's in MFC. I have a dialog box that displays the information of a camera when you connect it.

[image]

This is the resource code for that dialog box

```
IDD_PVSIMPLEUISAMPLE DIALOGEX 0, 0, 575, 284
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME
EXSTYLE WS_EX_APPWINDOW
CAPTION "PvSimpleUISample"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    PUSHBUTTON      "Select / Connect",IDC_CONNECT_BUTTON,10,16,86,16
    PUSHBUTTON      "Disconnect",IDC_DISCONNECT_BUTTON,97,16,87,16,WS_DISABLED
    LTEXT           "IP address",IDC_STATIC,10,41,45,8
    EDITTEXT        IDC_IP_EDIT,65,37,119,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_READONLY | WS_DISABLED
    LTEXT           "MAC address",IDC_STATIC,10,58,50,8
    EDITTEXT        IDC_MAC_EDIT,65,55,119,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_READONLY | WS_DISABLED
    LTEXT           "Manufacturer",IDC_STATIC,10,75,50,8
    EDITTEXT        IDC_MANUFACTURER_EDIT,65,72,119,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_READONLY | WS_DISABLED
    LTEXT           "Model",IDC_STATIC,10,93,44,8
    EDITTEXT        IDC_MODEL_EDIT,65,90,119,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_READONLY | WS_DISABLED
    LTEXT           "Name",IDC_STATIC,10,110,44,8
    EDITTEXT        IDC_NAME_EDIT,65,107,119,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_READONLY | WS_DISABLED
    GROUPBOX        "Connection",IDC_STATIC,4,4,187,123
    LTEXT           "Mode",IDC_STATIC,10,144,55,8
    COMBOBOX        IDC_MODE,66,141,118,30,CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | CBS_SORT | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
    LTEXT           "Channel",IDC_STATIC,9,160,56,8
    OMBOBOX        IDC_CHANNEL,66,157,118,30,CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | CBS_SORT | WS_DISABLED | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
    CONTROL         "Play",IDC_START,"Button",BS_OWNERDRAW | WS_TABSTOP,13,171,44,26
    CONTROL         "Stop",IDC_STOP,"Button",BS_OWNERDRAW | WS_TABSTOP,75,172,42,26
    CONTROL         "Settings",IDC_SETTINGS,"Button",BS_OWNERDRAW | WS_TABSTOP,135,172,43,26
    GROUPBOX        "Parameters and Controls",IDC_CONTROL_GROUP,4,206,187,73
    PUSHBUTTON      "Communication control",IDC_LINK_BUTTON,10,218,174,17,WS_DISABLED
    PUSHBUTTON      "Device control",IDC_DEVICE_BUTTON,10,237,174,17,WS_DISABLED
    PUSHBUTTON      "Image stream control",IDC_STREAMPARAMS_BUTTON,10,256,174,17,WS_DISABLED
    GROUPBOX        "Display",IDC_DISPLAY_GROUP,198,4,371,275
    PUSHBUTTON      "Display",IDC_DISPLAYPOS,205,17,355,254,NOT WS_VISIBLE | WS_DISABLED
    GROUPBOX        "Acquisition Control",IDC_CONTROL_GROUP2,4,128,187,77
END
```

I then made a new dialog box that opens when you click on the settings button. I copied a few of the lines over to the new dialog box but the actual data that is transmitted from the camera doesn't appear.

[image]

Here is the code for the settings dialog box

```
IDD_SETTINGS DIALOGEX 0, 0, 444, 319
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Settings"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,205,298,50,14
    LTEXT           "IP address",IDC_STATIC,10,41,45,8
    EDITTEXT        IDC_IP_EDIT,65,37,119,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_READONLY | WS_DISABLED
    LTEXT           "MAC address",IDC_STATIC,10,58,50,8
    EDITTEXT        IDC_MAC_EDIT,65,55,119,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_READONLY | WS_DISABLED
    LTEXT           "Manufacturer",IDC_STATIC,10,75,50,8
    EDITTEXT        IDC_MANUFACTURER_EDIT,65,72,119,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_READONLY | WS_DISABLED
    LTEXT           "Model",IDC_STATIC,10,93,44,8
    EDITTEXT        IDC_MODEL_EDIT,65,90,119,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_READONLY | WS_DISABLED
    LTEXT           "Name",IDC_STATIC,10,110,44,8
    EDITTEXT        IDC_NAME_EDIT,65,107,119,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_READONLY | WS_DISABLED
END
```

How do I get the data to appear in the dialog box? Do I need to make a whole class for it? Any help/advice would be aprreciated.

Comment: The answer is probably in the C++ code of the `IDD_PVSIMPLEUISAMPLE` dialog. Search for `IDC_DISPLAYPOS` in that code. Without seeing that code nobody can give a precise answer.

Comment: MFC encapsulates all Win32 resources in C++ classes. This includes dialogs. Asking whether you *"need to make a whole class for it"* doesn't make sense. You cannot have a dialog in MFC without a class. Unless you are using the Windows API directly. But then that's not MFC.

Comment: Ok yeah I wasn't sure because the main GUI is in its own .cpp file and I wasn't sure if the dialog box that I added needed its own .cpp file as well

Answer (score 0):

In first dialog, you can declare a second dialog's class object, use the object obtain the item control object then set data.
So you can do like this, in the setting button's callback function, add these codes:

```
CAAADialog::OnXXXButton()
{
     CBBBDialog dlgb;
     dlgb.DoModal();
     dlgb.GetDlgItem(IDC_IP_EDIT)->SetWindowText(m_strIp);
     dlgb.GetDlgItem(IDC_MAC_EDIT)->SetWindowText(m_strMac);
     dlgb.GetDlgItem(IDC_MANUFACTURER_EDIT)->SetWindowText(m_strManufacture);
     dlgb.GetDlgItem(IDC_NAME_EDIT)->SetWindowText(m_strName);
}
```